# Display same ids into single id

Tags: php, mysql

I have selected data from database and here is the result:

```
+--------+------------+
|  room  |    name    |
+--------+------------+
|   12   | John       |
|   13   | Marry      |
|   14   | Camilla    |
|   14   | Beatrix    |
+--------+------------+
```

And how can I print to my page by php code like this :

```
12 : John
13 : Marry
14 : Camilla, Beatrix
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: What you need is `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Modify the query to get the resultset you want. And you need `GROUP_CONCAT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use **Concat** and **Group_concat** to meet your exact need

```
select
concat(`room`, ' : ',group_concat(`name` separator ',')) as `Name`
FROM test
group by room;
```

Check [**Demo Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec8d9/8) Here

Answer (score 3):

try this, **group** and **group_concat** is what you search

```
select room,
GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM tablename
group by room;
```